# fix test with method equals() and override this one and hashCode()

Tags: java, unit-testing, object, overriding, roman-numerals

I try to test my code but the last System.out.printl does not answer, why?

```
@Test
public void testcopy(){
    RomanNumber rn1 = new RomanNumber("M");
    RomanNumber rn2 = new RomanNumber("M");
    RomanNumber rn1_copy = rn1;
    System.out.println("rn1 == rn1_copy is "
            + (rn1 == rn1_copy));
    System.out.println("rn1 == rn2 is " + (rn1 == rn2));
    System.out.println("rn1.equals(rn2) is " + (rn1.equals(rn2)));
}
```

Again, I want to override the `equals()` method of the Superclass `Object`, I tried this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if ((obj instanceof RomanNumber)) {
        RomanNumber decimal = (RomanNumber) obj;
        if (number == decimal.convertToInteger () && number.equals(decimal.convertToInteger) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, I post below all the code that it makes:

```
public class RomanNumber {

    private String number;

    public RomanNumber (String number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer equivalent of this roman number
     */
    public int convertToInteger ()  {
        int decimal = 0;
        int lastNumber = 0;
        // take the string roman number
        // write algorithm to convert it to int
        // return int

        number = number.toUpperCase();
        for (int x = number.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            char convertNumber = number.charAt(x);
            switch (convertNumber) {
                case 'M':
                    decimal = processDecimal(1000, lastNumber, decimal);
                    lastNumber = 1000;
                    break;

                case 'D':
                    decimal = processDecimal(500, lastNumber, decimal);
                    lastNumber = 500;
                    break;

                case 'C':
                    decimal = processDecimal(100, lastNumber, decimal);
                    lastNumber = 100;
                    break;

                case 'L':
                    decimal = processDecimal(50, lastNumber, decimal);
                    lastNumber = 50;
                    break;

                case 'X':
                    decimal = processDecimal(10, lastNumber, decimal);
                    lastNumber = 10;
                    break;

                case 'V':
                    decimal = processDecimal(5, lastNumber, decimal);
                    lastNumber = 5;
                    break;

                case 'I':
                    decimal = processDecimal(1, lastNumber, decimal);
                    lastNumber = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(decimal);
        return decimal;
    }

    private static int processDecimal(int decimal, int lastNumber, int lastDecimal) {
        if (lastNumber > decimal) {
            return lastDecimal - decimal;
        } else {
            return lastDecimal + decimal;
        }
    }

    private void validateState(String number){
        if (number == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null argument");

        if (number.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty string");


        if (!number.matches("^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Roman number");
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ((obj instanceof RomanNumber)) {
            RomanNumber decimal = (RomanNumber) obj;
            if (number == decimal.convertToInteger () && number.equals(decimal.convertToInteger) ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Fix what? What is broken?

Comment: What is "last System.out.printl does not answer" supposed to mean?

Comment: You forgot the brackets of the `convertToInteger` function at the end of this line: `if (number == decimal.convertToInteger () && number.equals(decimal.convertToInteger) )`

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st issue is

1) Incompatible operand types String and int

```
number == decimal.convertToInteger ()
```

You can't compare String and int directly

You can fix your issue by removing the line

2)`number.equals(decimal.convertToInteger())`

Here the number you are passing as `M`.
But the `decimal.convertToInteger()` returns 1000

So this is not right for comparing 2 objects are equal

How to fix?

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if ((obj instanceof RomanNumber)) {
        RomanNumber decimal = (RomanNumber)obj;
        if (number.equals(decimal.number)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right!
Thank you for the explain. I'm new in Java and I try to getting in better.